# How harmful is an insidious atmosphere?

Tags: traveller, environmental-hazards

An insidious atmosphere "requires the use of protective suits or vacc suits" (inherited from corrosive atmospheres) and "will defeat any personal protective measures in 2 to 12 hours." (CT-TTB p.83, "Atmosphere")

How harmful to a human is time spent in a corrosive or insidious atmosphere? Is it insta-death once the protective measures fail? Ongoing damage, which would quickly lead to unconsciousness, but perhaps your party can get you back to a safe environment?

Absent any rules-guidance on the matter, what sort of gaseous mixtures would be an "insidious" atmosphere, such that I can do my own RL research?

Comment: Pardon my limited knowledge of extraterrestrial meteorology, but, since an insidious atmosphere "defeats any personal protective measures in 2 to 12 hours," *and* such measures include vacc suits, does the game provide any support for an insidious atmosphere being *less* dangerous than [hard vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_exposure)?

Comment: I don't know much either; I'd suppose that the worst effect of hard vacuum--the boiling of bodily fluids--could be absent if the atmosphere is both standard pressure and horribly caustic?

Comment: (Even if the only thing bad for humans about the atmosphere is that it's insidiously caustic, [how long are turns in the version of *Traveller* you're playing?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11161/70032))

Comment: The situation imminent in my current game is out of combat-time; turns aren't really relevant. I've always assumed that, since Traveller has "nonexistent" and "thin" atmospheres at the opposite end of the spectrum from "corrosive" and "insidious", that there's plenty of gas present, but that it's not very friendly gas.

Comment: @HeyICanChan -- I can think of gasses *way* more dangerous than even hard vacuum (they'd also eat your vacc suit for lunch; only problem is they'd do it on a timescale far faster than what the game calls for).

Answer (score 3):

The answers you seek are in the Traveller SRD. After 2d6 hours, the character suffers 1d6 damage per round. (http://www.traveller-srd.com/core-rules/world-creation/)

> **Corrosive:** Corrosive atmospheres are highly dangerous. A character who breathes in a corrosive atmosphere will suffer 1d6 damage each round.
>
> **Insidious:** An insidious atmosphere is like a corrosive one, but it is
>   so corrosive that it attacks equipment as well. The chief danger in an
>   insidious atmosphere is that the toxic gases will destroy the seals
>   and filters on the character’s protective gear. An insidious
>   atmosphere worms its way past protection after 2d6 hours on average,
>   although vigilant maintenance or advanced protective gear can prolong
>   survival times.

Comment: Just because I'm very out of my depth in the broad universe of Traveller material: can you clarify what the provenance of the SRD is? I ask because I'm generally playing Classic; is this based on old material? Is it even the same company? Thanks!

Comment: The SRD was released by Mongoose as part of their 1st edition of the game.

Comment: Is this section compatible with Classic Traveller? My understanding is that decades passed between the first Mongoose edition and the 1977 original.

Comment: I think so. Specifically in this case, damage is handled the same way in both games by taking points directly from characteristics, and classic Traveller doesn't specify the damage done by a corrosive atmosphere (it merely says that such atmospheres "require the use of protective suits or vac suits." and nothing else.

Comment: I don't have access to "Special Supplement 2: Exotic Atmospheres". http://wiki.travellerrpg.com has a lot to say about atmospheres though if you care to look, including probable chemical combinations.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any rules on how long exposure to insidious atmospheres is survivable, but the MegaTraveller *World Builder's Handbook* does break them down into multiple subtypes:

- Gas Mix: Composed of a highly corrosive combination of gases, or a gas which is simply difficult to keep out, such as simple hydrogen
- Radiation
- Temperature
- Pressure

There's also about a page on "Unusual Atmospheric Compositions", which can be applied to exotic, corrosive, and insidious atmosphere types.  The listed compositions are: Carbon Dioxide, Nitrogen, Methane, Ammonia, Chlorine, Fluorine, Sulfur Compounds, and Hydrogen.

Given the wide range of situations that can provide an "insidious" atmosphere rating, it probably needs to be up to the referee to decide how long characters can survive there without proper protective gear.

Answer (score 2):

Special Supplement 2: Exotic Atmospheres (came from JTAS 17) does not prescribe a damage regime.

It suggests the following are some gas mixes:
carbon  dioxidecarbon  dioxide-sulphur  dioxidemethane-ammonia-hydrogenchlorine-nitrogenfluorine-carbon  dioxidefluorine-sulphur tetrachloride or otherSulphur compoundshydrogencarbon  dioxide-nitrogenchlorine-carbon  dioxidechlorine-disulphur  dichloridefluorine-nitrogen

Problems that lead to the 2d6 time period are gases infiltrating suits via penetration or by destruction of seals. Even plain old H2 (hydrogen) is a problem because it is so small it penetrates many seals which by itself would only represent a threat in two respects - displacement of O2 in your suit and the possibility of O2, H2 and a spark being in the same space - combustion with a fast boom.

You can, according to the above reference work, have high or low temps (you can't build portable heaters/coolers to compensate), high or low pressures with an atmosphere that is otherwise not so dangerous, or a combination of those two.

Then there is the radiation angle. In this case, the 2d6 value (if you don't pick one) represents maximum radiation dosage you can take before you get some serious radiation poisoning (and die).

I'm assuming some sort of anti-rad drug would help prolong the period you could operate in such an environment or help you recover more quickly (and avoid the dying part).

The SRD Daniel T's answer referenced is Mongoose Traveller. The two systems (MgT and CT) are compatible in so many ways (intentionally) that you can use the SRD's answer.

The special supplement also had some equipment to try to deal with the hostile environments.

Answer (score 0):

Traveller5 has suggestions on handling environmental damage. Corrosive and insidious atmospheres (as well as extreme heat and cold, and vacuum) will incapacitate and kill rather quickly; I believe they map to doing two dice of damage to an unprotected human every personal combat round - call it every minute, though there are slower-acting poisonous atmospheres, and there may always be mitigating circumstances.